# How to change caption fontsize in documentclass book?

Tags: captions, fontsize

I am using the document class book as follows

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright,titlepage,B5]{book}
```

for my thesis and the font size for the figure captions is the same as my text which I don't like so I want to change the font size, I use the caption package and I tried

```
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
```

but it gives me the error "option clash for caption package"!
any experience with this? any suggestion?

Comment: You appear to be loading the `caption`-package twice. There is probably some other package which loads it. might be `subfig`, or a related one. But it could be any package. Most likely loading the `caption`-package before the others will solve this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! From information, which you provide, cannot be reproduced your problem (actually, it is unlikely). SO please, provide small, complete document which can be complied and exhibits your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure what should I provide since my document is very big (a thesis), however, my problem is solved!     It was exactly what Runar Trollet pointed out so I changed the order of the packages in my preamble file as \usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfig}